# Installation on MSI Raider GE76

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Elementary OS 6.1 on my MSI Raider GE76 (Intel core i9 12XX + Nvidia RTX 3080Ti)

I created a bootable flash drive using Etcher.
Then I changed the boot priority in the BIOS to a flash drive, booted from it and chose "Install or try", the file check started, and then I see the console and it asks me to log in.

Alt+Ctrl+F7 doesn't work, I can't get the UI. And the installation has not started. Please help me. I can provide additional information, just tell me what.

**Update:**
I tried to do the same with Ubuntu 22.04.1.
Everything is ok.
The system has been installed. What am I doing wrong with elementary OS?